# What is the probability of choosing r objects from c different groups when there are m groups of n objects?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation

Suppose I have m groups of n objects each for a total of nm objects.  I am going to choose r of these nm objects.  I want to know what the probability is that my r objects come from c different groups.  Currently, I am using the formula:

$$
P(c) = { { n \choose c} \over { nm \choose r} } F(r, c)
$$

where:

$$
F(l, c) =
\begin{cases} 
    { n \choose l } & c = 1 \\
    \sum \limits_{i = 1} ^{l - c + 1} { { n \choose i } F(r - i, c - 1) }
\end{cases}
$$

It seems to me that this works because it works when m = 7, n = 10, amd r = 20, since the probabilities add up to 1, but does it work in general and is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Due to Brian's comment, I corrected my answer.

Suppose we select $c$ groups, and index them $1$ throught $c$. Let $A_i$ be the collection of sets taken from these groups, of size $r$ **not containing** an element from the $i$-th group.  Then we want to find: $$|A_1^C\cap\cdots\cap A_c^C|=|(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_c)^C|=\binom{cn}{r}-|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_c|$$
Next we note that for each $\emptyset\neq T\subseteq \{1,...,c\}$:
$$ 
\left|\,\underset{i\in T}{{\bigcap}}\,A_i\right|=\binom{(c-|T|)n}{r}
$$
(setting $\binom{s}{p}=0$ when $s<p$). Thus, using the inclusion-exclusion principle, and the fact that there are $\binom{c}{t}$ subsets of $\{1,...,c\}$ with $t$ elements:
$$
|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_c|=\sum_{\emptyset\neq T\subseteq \{1,...,c\}}{(-1)^{|T|-1}\left|\,\underset{i\in T}{{\bigcap}}\,A_i\right|}=\sum_{t=1}^c{(-1)^{t-1}\binom{c}{t}\binom{(c-t)n}{r}}
$$
Plugging this result into our previous equation, we see that once we select $c$ groups, we have:
$$
\binom{cn}{r}-\sum_{t=1}^c{(-1)^{t-1}\binom{c}{t}\binom{(c-t)n}{r}}=\sum_{t=0}^c{(-1)^{t}\binom{c}{t}\binom{(c-t)n}{r}}
$$
ways to select $r$ elements so that an element is selected from each group. Thus, the probability is:
$$
\frac{\binom{m}{c}}{\binom{mn}{r}}\sum_{t=0}^c{\left((-1)^{t}\binom{c}{t}\binom{(c-t)n}{r}\right)}
$$

Comment: @user2171981: This isn't correct. Let $m=r=4$, $c=3$, and $n=2$. Then we have $$\binom43\binom64-\binom42\binom44=60-6=54\;,$$ but in fact $48$ of the $70$ four-element sets hit exactly $3$ groups, $16$ hit exactly $4$ groups, and $6$ hit exactly $2$ groups. The problem is that the $60$ counts each of those last $6$ sets twice, but the formula subtracts them only once each.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are right. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Looks good; +1. I do see two small typos. In the third displayed line it should be $(-1)^{|T|-1}$, not $(-1)^{|T-1|}$, and in the next line it should be *Plugging*.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks. :)